# Adapting TensorFlow code droput layer to allow import into openCV

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras

### Background

I want to create and train a conv neural network, and implement the trained model on another device using c++.

The method I decided on after researching possible solutions was to create and train a model using keras, export the trained model as .pb then import it to a openCV Net model.

The openCV importNetFromTensorFLow function does not work in my case though as it cannot convert a dropout layer correctly. There has been a workaround/fix posted [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9673). It seems to me that unfortunately I will have to create a model with tensorflow instead of keras to implement the workaround.

### Issue

I have used a [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) to make a cnn, in an attempt to apply the aforementioned workaround/fix. But I cannot get it to work.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.python.framework import function
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession();

isTraining = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='isTraining')

@function.Defun(tf.float32, func_name='Dropout')
def my_dropout(x):
    return tf.layers.dropout(x, rate=0.1, training=isTraining)


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1],
                        strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

#First conv layer                           
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5,5,1,32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x,[-1,28,28,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image,W_conv1)+ b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

#Second conv layer
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5,5,32,64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1,W_conv2)+ b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

#Dense layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1,7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1)+ b_fc1)

#Dropout layer
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = my_dropout(h_conv2)

#Readout Layer
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
```

error : you must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'isTraining' with
dtype bool

If anyone could help me with the integration of this fix into the tutorial it would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

edit

```
#train
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correction_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correction_prediction, tf.float32)) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(20000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
            x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_:batch[1],keep_prob:0.5})

print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels,keep_prob:1}))
```

edit 2: new error

caused my MatMul_1 at line 66

```
y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
```

error

```
In[0] is not a matrix
```

Comment: Could you post the line you're using to execute training/evaluation? You probably need to add the `isTraining` placeholder to your feeddict.

Comment: i have posted it as an edit to my initial question

Comment: Sorry, I meant the part where you run the `train_step` tensor.

Comment: my bad, added it now

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `isTraining` placeholder in your feed dict when you run the `cross_entropy` or `train_step` tensors:

```
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob:0.5, isTraining: True})
```

(of course, pass `True` when you're training and `False` when you're not).

Edit: you also need

```
accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob:1, isTraining: False}))
```

And you can completely remove the keep_prob placeholder, both in the code and in the feed dicts, since you're never using it.

Second edit:

I missed a line, you also need to add it in

```
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
            x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0, isTraining: False})
```

above.

Comment: Thanks that has solved my issue although a new error has occurred, i will add it to my original question and if you feel like helping again you can.